# Sort array by name with array key

Tags: php

I have an array like this, how can I sort by "name"

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [name] => status_category_confide 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [name] => status_category_love 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 3 
        [name] => status_category_household 
    ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [id] => 4 
        [name] => status_category_family 
    ) 
    [4] => Array (
        [id] => 5 
        [name] => status_category_friends 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [id] => 6 
        [name] => status_category_colleague 
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
        [id] => 7 
        [name] => status_category_work 
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
        [id] => 8 
        [name] => status_category_ambition 
    ) 
)
```

I've tried using the "sort" function but it doesn't work

```
$get_status_mood=mysqli_query($con, "select id, name from category");
while ($gsm=mysqli_fetch_array($get_status_mood)) {
    //array_push($status_category, constant($gsm['name']));
    $status_category[] = array(
        "id"=>$gsm['id'],
        "name"=>$gsm['name']
    );
}

sort($status_category);
for ($i=0; $i<count($status_category); $i++) {
    echo"<option value='".$status_category[$i]['id']."'>".$status_category[$i]['name']."</option>";
}
```

I want to display the results in the order of the name

Comment: ^ That's for sorting it in PHP. But as the answer below suggests, you could (and probably should) sort it directly in the query instead.

Comment: Note to future visitors: There's no need to add more answers that's sorting it using PHP. That's all covered in the possible duplicate link above. Instead of repeating the, more or less, same answer, vote it as a duplicate instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort it using `array_column` and `array_multisort` functions.

```
$keys = array_column($array, 'name');

array_multisort($keys, SORT_ASC, $array);
```

Comment: Verry cool, thanks for your help,, simple code and work!

Answer (score 6):

Try the SQL order by option

```
$get_status_mood=mysqli_query($con, "select id, name from category order by name asc");
```

Comment: but I change the results from the database with constant()

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with usort this sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

```
   function cmp($a, $b)
{
  return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}
usort($vc_array, "cmp");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array();
$a[] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'status_category_confide');
$a[] = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'status_category_love');
$a[] = array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'status_category_household');

function cmp($x, $y) {
    if (strcmp($x['name'], $y['name']) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strcmp($x['name'], $y['name']) < 0) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($a, "cmp");

print_r($a);
```